# FInding multiple time reportings across columns

Tags: r, database, bioinformatics

I am trying to assess a dataset of injuries. The data comes from 4 sources (hospital, gp, self report, death) each with a time to the injury given in years (continuous variable). A single person may have an injury reported in one source, or multiple sources. I wish to know if the hospital injuries are reported elsewhere in other sources (any time to injury within 0.25 is considered the same injury).

I therefore want to create a column saying Hospital_elsewhere_1 where if there is a time in the Hospital_1 column, the column Hospital_elsewhere_1 will say "Hospital" and if there is a time within 0.25 in any of the other columns (not including Hospital) it will also include a text, seperated by a | of the source.

FOr instance if there is a injury at 65.44 years in Hospital_1 and a injury at 65.42 in GP_1 and 65.43 in self_report it would say "Hospital|GP|self_report".

I would want to do this for each of the hospital columns so there would be a Hospital_elsewhere_(i)

A example dataset is below

```
library(tibble)
set.seed(123)

example_data <- tibble(
  id = 1:30,
  Hospital_1 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(25, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE),
  Hospital_2 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(25, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE),
  Hospital_3 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(25, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE),
  Hospital_4 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(25, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE),
  GP_1 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(25, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE),
  GP_2 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(25, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE),
  GP_3 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(25, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE),
  GP_4 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(25, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE),
  GP_5 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(25, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE),
  GP_6 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(25, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE),
  GP_7 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(25, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE),
  GP_8 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(25, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE),
  GP_9 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(25, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE),
  GP_10 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(25, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE),
  self_report_1 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(15, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE),
  self_report_2 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(15, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE),
  self_report_3 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(15, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE),
  self_report_4 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(15, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE),
  death_1 = sample(c(NA, round(runif(25, 1, 80), 2)), 30, replace = TRUE)
)

for (i in 1:10) {
  index <- sample(1:30, 1)  
  gp_value <- round(runif(1, 1, 80), 2)  
  example_data[index, paste0("GP_", 1:4)] <- gp_value 
  example_data[index, paste0("Hospital_", 1:4)] <- gp_value + runif(1, -0.25, 0.25)
}
```

Comment: quick question - is it 0.25 from the hospital or from any other source?  For example, self reported 66.01, GP 66.26, hospital 66.50 - would we have all three?

Comment: It may help if you provide data that a bit more manageable (emphasis on the *minimal* in minimal reproducible example) - ie, 2-3 columns per prefix, not 4 to 10. Good luck!

Comment: It would be 0.25 from any source, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Transform your data with one (`list`) column per location:

   ```r
   library(dplyr)
   library(purrr)
   library(tidyr)
   (list_df <- example_data %>%
     pivot_longer(names_to = c("Type", "nr"), 
                  names_pattern = "(.*)_(\\d*)", 
                  cols = -id,
                  names_transform = list(nr = as.integer)) %>%
     summarize(vals = list(value), .by = c(id, Type)) %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = Type, values_from = vals) %>%
     relocate(GP, .after = Hospital))
   # # A tibble: 30 × 5
   #       id Hospital  GP         self_report death    
   #    <int> <list>    <list>     <list>      <list>   
   #  1     1 <dbl [4]> <dbl [10]> <dbl [4]>   <dbl [1]>
   #  2     2 <dbl [4]> <dbl [10]> <dbl [4]>   <dbl [1]>
   #  3     3 <dbl [4]> <dbl [10]> <dbl [4]>   <dbl [1]>
   # [...]
   ```
2. For each `Hospital` check whether there is any location within the time range:

   ```r
   detect_reportings <- function(other, Hospital) {
     imap_chr(set_names(Hospital, paste0("Hospital_", seq_along(Hospital))),
              ~ if_else(any(abs(other - .x) <= .25), cur_column(), NA_character_)) %>%
     list()
   }
   ```

   This function will eventually return a character vector of length `4` (== number of hospitals) for each other location which is `NA` if there is noevent within the time range and the name of the location otherwise:

   ```r
   (dist_check <- list_df %>%
     group_by(id) %>%
     mutate(across(GP:death, ~ detect_reportings(.x[[1]], Hospital[[1]])),
            Hospital = set_names(if_else(is.na(Hospital[[1]]), NA_character_, "Hospital"),
                                 paste0("Hospital_", seq_along(Hospital[[1]]))) %>%
                        list()))
   # # A tibble: 30 × 5
   # # Groups:   id [30]
   #       id Hospital  GP        self_report death    
   #    <int> <list>    <list>    <list>      <list>   
   #  1     1 <chr [4]> <chr [4]> <chr [4]>   <chr [4]>
   #  2     2 <chr [4]> <chr [4]> <chr [4]>   <chr [4]>
   #  3     3 <chr [4]> <chr [4]> <chr [4]>   <chr [4]>
   # [...]

   dist_check$GP[[16]]
   ## Hospital_3 and Hospital_4 were within the .25 range
   # Hospital_1 Hospital_2 Hospital_3 Hospital_4 
   #         NA         NA       "GP"       "GP" 
   example_data[16, c(4:5, 8, 14)]
   # # A tibble: 1 × 4
   #   Hospital_3 Hospital_4  GP_3  GP_9
   #        <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
   # 1       25.6       19.9  25.4  19.7
   ```
3. The final step is to merge these checks:

   ```r
   merge_reportings <- function(...) {
     cbind(...) %>%
       as_tibble() %>%
       unite("result", sep = "|", na.rm = TRUE) %>%
       t() %>%
       c() %>%
       set_names(paste0("Hospital_elsewhere_", seq_along(..1))) %>%
       as.list() %>%
       as_tibble()
   }
   res <- dist_check %>%
     reframe(merge_reportings(Hospital[[1]], GP[[1]], self_report[[1]], death[[1]]))
   print(res, n = 10L)

   # # A tibble: 30 × 5
   #       id Hospital_elsewhere_1 Hospital_elsewhere_2 Hospital_elsewhere_3 Hospital_elsewhere_4
   #    <int> <chr>                <chr>                <chr>                <chr>               
   #  1     1 Hospital             Hospital             Hospital             "Hospital"          
   #  2     2 Hospital             Hospital             Hospital             "Hospital"          
   #  3     3 Hospital             Hospital             Hospital             "Hospital"          
   #  4     4 Hospital             Hospital             Hospital             "Hospital"          
   #  5     5 Hospital             Hospital             Hospital             "Hospital"          
   #  6     6 Hospital             Hospital             Hospital|GP          "Hospital|GP"       
   #  7     7 Hospital|GP          Hospital|GP          Hospital|GP          "Hospital|GP"       
   #  8     8 Hospital|GP          Hospital|GP          Hospital|GP          "Hospital|GP"       
   #  9     9 Hospital             Hospital             Hospital             "Hospital"          
   # 10    10 Hospital             Hospital             Hospital             "Hospital"          
   # # ℹ 20 more rows
   # # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
   ```